# Wait for AWS RDS native sql backup to be finished

Tags: sql-server, powershell, batch-file, amazon-rds

When creating an EC2 or RDS instance in batch or powershell, you can run the built-in `aws rds wait db-instance-available --db-instance-identifier 'myDbInstance'` to wait for it to be available before running further commands against it.

I have a script that restores an RDS snapshot into a new instance ($devInstanceDnsName), and then backup a single database from that instance (in MS SQL) to S3.
In powershell, to run the native backup, you run `sqlcmd -X -b -S "tcp:$devInstanceDnsName,1433" -d dbName -U dbUser -P dbPwd -Q "exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database @source_db_name='dbName', @s3_arn_to_backup_to='arn:aws:s3:::backupsbucket/$backupFileName', @overwrite_S3_backup_file=1"`.

That is an asynchronous task, it schedules the backup and returns immediately. But how can the script know when the native backup has completed, and continue execution, synchronously?

Answer (score 5):

I've done a simple powershell function called like this:

```
Wait-RdsNativeBackupSuccess -server "$devInstanceDnsName,1433" -database dbName -user dbUser -pwd dbPwd
```

and defined like this:

```
function Wait-RdsNativeBackupSuccess($server, $database, $user, $pwd)
{
    $startDate = Get-Date
    $timeOutminutes = 45
    $retryIntervalSeconds = 30

    do {
            $awsResponse = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Username $user -Password $pwd -Query "exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status @db_name='dbName'" -DisableCommands -AbortOnError
            Write-Host $awsResponse.lifecycle $awsResponse."% complete"
        
            if($awsResponse.lifecycle -eq "SUCCESS") {break}
            start-sleep -seconds $retryIntervalSeconds

    } while ($startDate.AddMinutes($timeOutminutes) -gt (Get-Date))

}
```

It calls the [rds_task_status](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/native-backup-rds-sql-server/) sproc every X seconds, for a maximum of X minutes, until it gets a lifecycle value of "SUCCESS".

You can of course improve this:

- add a return code or throw in case of timeouts,
- handle the lifecycle value of error, maybe showing the value of task_info which will have the error in it.
- pass in more parameters to make it more generic (like port number of timeouts and retries), etc.

Output looks like this:

```
Task created successfully.
Task Id: 1
CREATED 0
CREATED 0
CREATED 0
IN_PROGRESS 0
IN_PROGRESS 0
IN_PROGRESS 5
IN_PROGRESS 5
IN_PROGRESS 10
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, helped a lot! I want to add that this query checking the status currently does not work with multiple jobs that ran for this database. If there has previously been a job that succeeded, the newly created timer to check the current status will eventually evaluate to `CREATED SUCCESS 0 100`.

Answer (score 0):

change the query to to use task_id instead of db_name.  Then you are checking status of that task, not all operations on that database.